# Where can I bulk-buy cheap parmesan?

Tags: cheese, shopping, budget-cooking

My friend planted three rows of basil in his garden to make pesto, and now we need to source roughly 25-50lbs of parmesan. With that kind of quantity, cheaper is better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The price of genuine-sealed-and-certified parmagiano reggiano is quite high and fairly consistent, especially for more aged varieties.  I think your best bet to save money will be to use a similar parmagiano reggiano cousin, such as grana padano, romano, or a quality Argentinian reggianito.  As a second-tier approach, you might look at domestic Parmesan, but use caution as it may not have the same quality as a one of the Italian imports.

As for genuine Parmesan: you're buying at least a couple hundred dollars of cheese, and this gives you some bargaining power.  Buy or ask to taste a small sample of whatever you're considering, and try to negotiate; managers may be willing to offer you a bulk discount.  I'd gather a couple quotes from cheese shops, try prices at your local Costco/Sam's Club, and talk to the upscale grocery stores in your area.

As far as pricing goes, I've seen genuine-seal-and-everything Parmagiano Reggiano on sale at about $12-13/lbs at my local Southern Season.  I generally expect to pay $18-22/lbs at upscale grocery stores for Parmesan, with remarkably little variation between stores.  Your standard grocery stores tend to sell small blocks of inferior-quality and freshness Parmesan for similar prices.

In contrast, grana padano runs around $12-13/lbs on average at my local Trader Joe's, and might be available for under $10/lbs with a good sale.  I usually buy blocks of that for general cooking use, as it is close enough in taste and much cheaper.

Comment: I would also add that Pecorino Romano is usually cheaper than Parmigiano Reggiano and is traditionally included in pesto along with it (the traditional cheese is actually *Fiore Sardo*, which is also made with sheep milk, but that is very difficult to find outside of Italy).

Comment: It should be noted that although domestic (*i.e.*, US-made) paremsan-style cheese can be much cheaper than the "real" stuff, [a recent Cooks Illustrated taste test](http://bit.ly/ohqIjy) concluded that real Parmigiano-Reggiano is far superior.  A panel of blind taste testers could easily pick out the real cheese; the domestic versions had very different textures and were described as "rubbery, salty, and bland."

Comment: @ESultanik: That cook's illustrated taste test isn't by any means comprehensive, given the variety of cheese producers.  A high-quality domestic may be acceptable for this use, although I'd much sooner use grana padano. I think you'd have to compare a couple, and stay away from the cheap grocery store "grated Parmesan." (I use quotes, because the connection between that and real reggiano is tenuous at best).

Comment: @BobMcGee: True, they did only compare cheeses from six different domestic producers.

Comment: Updated [Cook's Illustrated Taste Test](https://www.cooksillustrated.com/taste_tests/1695-supermarket-parmesan?incode=MCSCD00L0&ref=new_search_experience_1) article.

Answer (score 3):

Costco has good quality, large chunks of parmesan for a lot cheaper than grocery stores.

Comment: I can't find a quote anywhere on their site.  What's the price like at your local Costco?

Comment: It's been a long time since I had to buy a chunk, but I think it's somewhere in the 9-10 dollars/pound range.  For comparison my local supermarket price is around 16 dollars/pound.

Comment: True. Costco is generally good value when it comes to cheese..

Answer (score 2):

Well, it's not first frost yet in most areas, so you might still have time on this --

I'd ask your local Italian restaurants where they get their cheese from.  Odds are, they're not paying the grocery store $15-20/lb prices.

In my area, there's Restaurant Depot, which sells Parmagiano Reggiano cheaper than some of the regular grocery stores sell other cheaper varieties.  The thing is, they sell it in chunks about 1/8 of a wheel or larger if I recall correctly (which is about 10lb a chunk ... maybe they had 5lb chunks, but I don't think it was smaller than that), and they'll only give membership cards to people who can prove they have a business or a non-profit ... but it's possible that a restaurant who already has a good source might be willing to resell some to you.

Answer (score 1):

We find good values at our local ethnic market -- specifically, in my case, Phonecia Specialty Foods in Houston, TX. They have no problems selling in bulk by the wheel.

Answer (score -2):

This is just plain silly!  You can get grated domestic parmesan at ca 4.14/lb in bulk foods section of WINCO supermarkets. Plenty of flavor, particularly if making pesto

Comment: "US domestic parmesan" is like "US champagne" --- an oxymoron.